# Buld prediction intervals for glmmTMB

Tags: distributions, predictive-models, prediction-interval, misspecification, glmmtmb

I'm using glmmTMB to build a mixed effect logistic model from which I want to draw predictions.

The predict() function applied to a glmmTMB model allows extracting the ML prediction and the relative standard error. I want to build a predictive distribution for the prediction in the form of $C$ cases out of $N$ trials.

Given prediction $\hat{m}$ with standard error $\hat{se}$, the simpler approach would be:

$$lwr,upr=logit^{-1}(\hat{m} \pm 1.96 \times \hat{se}) \times N$$

But that would be ignoring the uncertainty related to the binomial distributed problem I am trying to estimate? so, in a more Bayesian approach, shouldn't the 95% intervals be:

$$lwr,upr : P(lwr < pred < upr) = 0.95$$
$$pred \sim Binom(\theta, N)$$
$$\theta\sim \mathcal{N}(\hat{m},  \hat{se}^2)$$

Of course this approach gives slightly larger intervals, but I am able to compute it only via simulation, which is computationally expensive.